# How do I generate an "apply from" rather than "apply plugin" from custom Grails profile?

Tags: grails, profile

I have a custom Grails 4.x profile. I want to generate an "apply from" entry for my application build.

```
apply from:"${rootProject.projectDir}/gradle/clover.gradle"
```

What do I specify in my profile.yml to generate this? I cannot find any examples or documentation of this and so I am wondering if this is even possible.

```
build:
    plugins:
        - war
        - org.grails.grails-web
    from:
        - "${rootProject.projectDir}/gradle/clover.gradle"
    excludes:
        - org.grails.grails-core
```

Comment: The profile repository does not support that currently. You might file an issue or PR to https://github.com/grails-profiles

Answer (score 0):

I removed the references from the profile.xml and just added a line in the skeleton's build.gradle file which gets appended to a generated application. It appears after the dependencies but I verified this worked.

```
apply from:"${project.projectDir}/gradle/clover.gradle"
```